# Problem updating node module from drupal 6 to drupal 7

Tags: migrations, updating

I am trying to update my drupal version from 6 to 7. I have a problem, I use the next link http://localhost/drupal6/update.php and when the process said "Updating node module" it never finish.

[image]

I use WAMPSERVER in WINDOWS 8.1

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be with the Locale module. I would suggest disabling the Locale module in D6, running the D7 update.php, then enabling Locale and running update.php again.

Comment: Hello James, thanks for your answer. I have solved my warning (I don´t know how) but it not solved my problem installing node module.